Unable to open gnome-control-center - undefined symbol: gbm_bo_create_with_modifiers2
I woke up today and tried to change some basic settings in gnome-control-manager on my Ubuntu 22.04
It does not open.
To fix it, I try:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center display gnome-control-center
None of this seems to work
This is the error that I am facing while trying to gnome-control-center :

gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_create_with_modifiers2

Since error is on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37, I try to apt list -a libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
and sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37=2.36.0-2ubuntu1 to revert to a previous version, based on the available options.
But this isn't possible as well because:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.36.0-2ubuntu1) but 2.44.0-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

And then I try to fix this dependency:
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37=2.36.0-2ubuntu1 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18=2.36.0-2ubuntu1
But this ultimately crashed my GUI and reverts me to tty1 mode :)
I then perform sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm3
And now I am back to the beginning. Please help ;-;

Does this answer your question? Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

gbm_bo_create_with_modifiers2 is a function supposed to be exported from libgbm.so, which is provided by your GPU graphics driver. But it is relatively new (dated 2020 in mesa). If you got older Linux platform, most likely your drivers are outdated, or very new GPU drivers may not exist at all.
My guess is that gnome-control-center got updated, expecting that API will exist, which is not the case.
What is your OS version, your GPU hardware and GPU driver?
